# XQuery an XML files with different namespace in attributes (epub:type)

Tags: xml, html, namespaces, xquery, epub

I'm trying to make a query over an XML (XHTML5) with two different namespaces, one for the tags and one for the attributes.

This is an example:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" 
xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops">

<head>
    <link href="primo.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <title>Incipit</title>


</head>
<body>

    <p id="notauno" epub:type="footnote">Il nome della rosa è una cosa.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

So, I have a "type" attribute from epub namespace. I cannot understand the right XQuery syntax to read, for example, the value of epub:type in p tag ("footnote"). I tried different code, like this:

```
xquery version "1.0";

declare namespace epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf";
declare namespace h="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml";

let $sorgente:=fn:doc("file.xhtml")

for $nota in $sorgente//h:p
return data ($nota/@epub:type)
```

But there is an error I can not see. If someone could help me, thanks in advance.

Comment: "there is an error" -- _which_ error? What output do you get, what is the expected output for the input you provided?

Comment: My expected output is "footnote". I got an "Your query returned an empty sequence."

Comment: by any chance are you using MarkLogic ?

Comment: I tried using Oxygen's Saxon and BaseX 8.2.1

Answer (score 1):

Looks like a typo to me. The XML has `epub` prefix mapped to the following URI :

```
xmlns:epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops"
```

while in the XQuery, the same prefix is mapped to :

```
epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/opf";
```

Notice the difference between `ops` and `opf`

Comment: You are right. Facepalm. It was a typo. Thank you a lot.

Answer (score 1):

Your declaration for the epub namespace has a typo.
should be:

```
declare namespace epub="http://www.idpf.org/2007/ops";
```

And then it will work;-)